# air resistance in sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics

This is my first time working with sprite kit and am trying to figure out how I would implement the effect of air resistance. I want to be able to create two different sprite nodes and have one behave like a bubble and the other like a rock. Right now they behave like they would in a vacuum (ignoring the fact that a bubble would pop in a vacuum).

So the questions is how can I add air resistance? I've tried linear dampening, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: i believe skfieldnide can be used to simulate wind: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014163

Comment: Physically, air resistance is a force that points in the direction opposite the velocity (in the frame of the air) and has magnitude proportional to the square of the magnitude of the velocity. How you would implement that in sprite-kit, I have no idea.

Comment: When you changed the linear damping property what did you expect to happen and what actually happened? Linear damping is used to simulate air resistance or drag in Sprite Kit.

Comment: Linear damping was the correct way, I just wash;t getting the expected behavior. After changing other attributes I now have the desired behavior

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you now. For the benefit of other SO visitors, you might consider editing your question to clarify what behavior you expected and then posting an answer with your solution.